# CodeIgniter URL Rewrite for Nginx Server

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting, nginx

This is my CodeIgniter Controller class code.

```
class View extends MY_Controller
{

    function index($number)
    {
        .....
    }
    .......
}
```

Through browser, I can access the View class's index method using this URL

```
http://localhost/view/index/12
```

So, my question is

is there any efficient way to rewrite the URL, for example, into this URL

```
http://localhost/view/12
```

My web server is Nginx.

Comment: You should be able to access http://localhost/view/12 directly. It defaults to index().

Comment: hmm.. no, it makes 404 error in my server. -_-; I don't know why?

Comment: I think this two answers got it right. It just works for me with a .htaccess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`index()` is called by default  , but if you want to do it for other functions , you can make use of URI Routing feature in CI.

Add this to routes.php in config directory.

```
$route['view/(:num)'] = "view/index/$1";
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove the trailing `index` from all controllers using the following configuration in Nginx

```
# removes trailing "index" from all controllers
if ($request_uri ~* index/?$)
{
    rewrite ^/(.*)/index/?$ /$1 permanent;
}
```

Explicitly you can route the URLs from CodeIgniter Routing file located in

`./application/config/routes.php`

Insert this code. This should work for both Nginx or Apache Servers.

```
// hide index from all controllers
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = "$1/index/$2";

// hide only from View Controller
$route['view/(:any)'] = "view/index/$1";

// hide only from View with numeric parameter
$route['view/(:num)'] = "view/index/$1";
```

Find more information about [**Nginx URL Rewrite**](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule) from documentation. Hope this helps you. Thanks!!